# Error when attempting to add MVC classes into an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration

I have a large asp.net project to which I want to add MVC functionality.  I have added the necessary references into the project (System.Web.Mvc (v 2.0), System.Web.Abstractions (v 3.5) and System.Web.Routing (v 3.5) and amended all the required files (Global.asax (routing requirements), the web.config, project (Controllers and View folders) and created a basic HomeController and ViewPage.

When I run the application and attempt to go to the controller via {serverpath}\Home I am getting the error "An unhandled exception has occurred - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."  I've tried browsing the net but the error is too vague; is there a good way to identify exactly why the assembly cannot load?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registed the assemblies in the web.config?